# How to access both http and https laravel project

Tags: php, laravel

I have project created in laravel and I already configure it to https by adjusting the **APP_URL=https://www.olympusfood.ca/** in ENV file of laravel folder. I find out when i type http://www.olympusfood.ca in incognito it says that You don't have permission to access / on this server.

- I follow the instruction that i need to copy .htaccess to the root folder of project

[image]

I hope someone help me to these thanks.

Comment: Check this document https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/redirects#creating-redirects

Answer (score 1):

HTTPS/HTTP is not a issue Laravel is concerned with. You need to do some URL redirects outside Laravel first.

On your server/in the control panel of your host you need to create a domain that serves HTTP and redirect all requests to it to HTTPS.

If it's using Apache you can do that with .htaccess and mod_rewrite.

If you are using another web server there are ways to do it too.

Here are [some mod_rewrite examples](https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/9821/38/redirect-to-https-on-apache)